# How to get ARKit or ARCore different session and devices get same result with local anchors

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, indoor-positioning-system, indoor-map

I'm using ARCore and ARKit to set up augmented reality (AR) in a particular space. Each time I have a new session with visitors, I face an issue with relocating previously set anchors across different devices and sessions. My questions are:

1. Do I need to calculate parameters like rotation, angle, degree, distance, and use the compass to relocate these anchors?
2. Or, is there a built-in feature that can help position it correctly?

To provide some context, I have several local anchors set up. Since my space frequently has visitors, I'm considering using a QR code. Visitors could scan this code, which would help in launching the right local anchor points.

The challenge is that each time ARKit or ARCore starts, it initializes at a zero position. It doesn't recognize any previously set anchors or sessions. Moreover, I have a 3D model in a .glb file format where I want to place anchors. I can't expect users to always start from a specific location. My idea is for them to scan the QR code whenever needed, which will lead them to the right anchor points.

I hope this clarifies my concerns. If you need more details, please let me know, and I can explain further.

I have tried to calculate xyz on many parameaters. Based on angle, distance, rotation, sides and many more.